# Can I use "in addition to" to mention new information?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, usage

Can "in addition to" be used to introduce information not mentioned before in the text? Is it weird?

For example,

> In addition to doing A, I also did B.

But this sentence is the first time A appears in the whole text. I kind of have the feeling that A should be talked about before using this sentence, or is this just fine?

Comment: It’s okay but not compelling. I’d suggest “I did A and I. I also did B.” Never be frightened to try for short snappy sentences when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can "in addition to" be used to introduce information not mentioned before in the text?

Yes

> Is it weird?

No.

If the context about A is very clear, then it's quite reasonable to introduce new information with A.

For example:

"I was trying to figure out how a person might invest in the real estate market. In addition to buying a few books, I also asked a coworker who knows a lot about it, and checked out a local website with many sales listings."

Fine.

Let's experiment with a different example that has a less extensive intro:

"I recently visited Boston. In addition to buying a few books, I also went to the museum."

This seems acceptable, although maybe a bit hurried.

Finally, if the first part were removed and you started abruptly with "In addition" it wouldn't make sense. You should not introduce a completely new topic with "In addition".